# Convert to date string object in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a `DataFrame` where the date is in this format:

```
2022-10-13T00:05:05-07:00
```

I want to convert this into date object. `pd.to_datetime` is failing. Can anyone help me to convert this in to a datetime object?

Comment: What is error ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post the code you're currently trying and the error associated with it. Only then can the community help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.to_datetime("2022-10-13T00:05:05-07:00").date())
#2022-10-13
```